# Efficient Way to Create Subcollection From List With Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking for an **efficient** way to add a List of Documents to a sub collection of elements in Firestore using Flutter. Currently I can do the following:

```dart
documents.forEach((doc) => Firestore.instance
          .collection('mainCollection')
          .document('mainDoc')
          .collection('mySubCollection')
          .add(doc));
```

What I'm wondering is is this the most efficient way to add a list of elements, as this list may be quite large, or is there an operation for this that I can't seem to find. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Add each document individually.
2. Use a [batch write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), which is limited to 500 documents (see [WriteBatch](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/WriteBatch-class.html) for Flutter).

Any more than 500 documents, and you will not be able to add them all in one operation, as there are no other bulk add operations.  A batch write might be slightly faster than individual inserts. I suggest benchmarking to find out which one is best for your case.

Comment: does each document count as a write operation with a batch write or does each batch count as 1 write operation. Thanks for your quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore API doesn't have any `addAll` that I know of, but you could use a [generator function](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generators) to add each document asynchronously, and know when it's done, because the `Stream` returned by the generator will be `done`.